# How to get the all item from Gridview that I have select?

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I use Fragment which  `extends Fragment implements MultiChoiceModeListener`.

And a `class extends BaseAdapter`.

I can get the only position When I select the item from Gridview like the following code:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mActionText.setText(formatString(fileListView.getCheckedItemCount()));

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    Log.i(TAG, "fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions(); = " + checkedItems);
    if (checkedItems != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                String item = fileListView.getAdapter().getItem(
                                      checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
                Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected");
            }
        }
    }
    mode.invalidate();

    }
```

And the value is like the following log:

```
EG Player(21867): fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions(); = android.util.SparseBooleanArray@43625dc0
I/MJPEG Player(21867): tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.Model.FileNode@43c4b7e8 was selected
```

What is the value of item mean ?

Does there has other method can get all the item that I have select from Gridview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Martin,

```
       You can use the following code snippet :-
```

in the view.setOnCheckedChangeListener

```
                  if(isChecked){
                        extention = data[position];
                    }
```

Where data is the array if items which you shown in the gridview.

Comment: So...I can not get all the item I have select once time by Android API? I have to use loop to remember the the item I have select by myself ?

Comment: you can. Please you apply the for loop according to data.length() and get all selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Your BooleanArray has the indices of the selected items. However, you are attempting to print objects. You should print their indices instead. Change `Log.i(TAG, item + " was selected");` to `Log.i(TAG, i + " was selected");`